# Tkinter tab not opening again and again

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to open this login window again and again but its not opening again and again how to do it?

It is ending after 2 times. Is there any alternative way to do this?

```
import login
import tkinter as tk
from importlib import reload

def loop():
    root.destroy()
    reload (login)

# Create the root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a label widget
label = tk.Label(root, text="Login")

# Create a button widget
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=loop)

# Pack the widgets into the root window
label.pack()
button.pack()

# Start the mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no need to repeat your question *again and again*.

Comment: You don't really want to `import` the code every time. You want to import it ahead of time, so that there is a *function you can call* that does the important thing, and then *call that function* each time. The *point* of the `import` system is to make it so that a module's code *doesn't* run again every time an `import` happens, so that you can write `import` statements everywhere you need the module, without worrying about the code running again when you don't want it to. Please see the linked duplicates for details.

Comment: (Giving a more specific answer would require seeing a [mre] of the code in the `login` module, but this is not actually necessary in order to *understand the problem*. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a help desk; answers here are not about fixing your code, but about answering your question and making sure you understand.)